# Sending TCP urgend data through the socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

How to implement transfer control using "TCP urgent data" in Java.

I implemented a client-server application for transferring a file using the TCP protocol. Server is parallel. It is also necessary to implement transmission control using urgent data. I did not find a solution on Java on the Internet.

Server class:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private static final String FILE_PATH_SERVER = "C:\\Users\\anduser\\IdeaProjects\\Shafarenko_LR1\\src\\main\\resources\\fileServer.txt";

    public static final File FILE_SERVER = new File(FILE_PATH_SERVER);

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true)
            new ClientHandler(serverSocket.accept()).start();
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    private static class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private DataOutputStream out;
        private FileInputStream in;

        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeInt((int) FILE_PATH_SERVER.length());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH_SERVER);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (true) {
                byte buf[] = new byte[8];
                int len = 0;
                try {
                    len = in.read(buf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (len == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private String generatedFileClient = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10) + ".txt";
    private String FILE_PATH_CLIENT = "C:\\Users\\anduser\\IdeaProjects\\Shafarenko_LR1\\src\\test\\resources\\" + generatedFileClient;

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private FileOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private File fileCilent;

    public File getFileClient() {
        return new File(FILE_PATH_CLIENT);
    }

    public void getFile() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int len;
        byte buf[] = new byte[8];
        int fileSize;
        fileSize = in.readInt();
        while (i < fileSize) {
            len = in.read(buf);
            if (len == -1) {
                break;
            }
            i += len;
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
    }

    public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH_CLIENT);
        in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class TestClient {
    @Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 1000, timeOut = 0)
    public void givenClient() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        Client client = new Client();
        client.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 555);
        client.getFile();
        softAssert.assertTrue(FileUtils.contentEquals(Server.FILE_SERVER, client.getFileClient()), "The files differ!");
        client.stopConnection();
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the wrong terms. How do you define "urgent data" and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: can you please past console output of server and client and test? Also the original and generated file content.

Comment: Did my answer help you or is there some ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

From Harold's "[Java Network Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028420.do)":

> TCP includes a feature that sends a single byte of “urgent” data out
>   of band. This data is sent immediately. Furthermore, the receiver is
>   notified when the urgent data is received and may elect to process
>   the urgent data before it processes any other data that has already
>   been received. Java supports both sending and receiving such urgent
>   data. The sending method is named, obviously enough, sendUrgentData():

```
public void sendUrgentData(int data) throws IOException
```

> This method ***sends the lowest-order byte**** of its argument almost immediately. If
>   necessary, any currently cached data is flushed first.
>
> How the receiving end responds to urgent data is a little confused,
>   and varies from one platform and API to the next. Some systems receive
>   the urgent data separately from the regular data. However, the more
>   common, more modern approach is to place the urgent data in the
>   regular received data queue in its proper order, tell the application
>   that urgent data is available, and let it hunt through the queue to
>   find it. By default, Java ignores urgent data received from a socket.
>   However, if you want to receive urgent data inline with regular data,
>   you need to set the OOBINLINE option to true using these methods:
>   By default, Java ignores urgent data received from a socket. However,
>   if you want to receive urgent data inline with regular data, you need
>   to set the OOBINLINE option to true using these methods:

```
public void setOOBInline(boolean on) throws SocketException
public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException
```

> The default for OOBINLINE is false. This code fragment turns OOBINLINE
>   on, if it’s turned off:

```
if (!s.getOOBInline()) s.setOOBInline(true);
```

> Once OOBINLINE is turned on, any ***urgent data*** that arrives will be
>   placed on the socket’s input stream to be ***read in the usual way***. ***Java
>   does not distinguish it from nonurgent data***. That makes it less than
>   ideally useful, but if you have a particular byte (e.g., a Ctrl-C)
>   that has special meaning to your program and never shows up in the
>   regular data stream, then this would enable you to send it more
>   quickly.

There are a lot of examples on GitHub of using `sendUrgentData()` and `setOOBInline()`. E.g. [this](https://github.com/RingTam/JDKStudy/blob/14d306c00b8340071c8af7f37be3c73b7a86af73/src/TestSocketOOBInline.java).

******* - remember that almost all implementations really can provide only ***one byte of "out-of-band data"***.

Read more:

- [Is urgent tcp data acknowledged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241437/is-urgent-tcp-data-acknowledged)
- [Difference between push and urgent flags in TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153566/difference-between-push-and-urgent-flags-in-tcp)